# Installed Commerce Drupal 7 with Examples but Cannot create Add a Product Action for new Product line

Tags: commerce, actions

I am sure this is a newbie question and I apologize in advance but I have spent most of the day trying to solve this problem.

From the examples that I have seen, apparently creation of a product type (*Home->Administration->Store Settings->Product Settings->Product Types->Add product type*) should result in the automatic creation of a link for that product type in the Add a Product menu (*Home->Administration->Products->Actions->Add a Product*).

It is not doing this for me. More than likely I am making a basic mistake somewhere but I can not find what it is.

Would greatly appreciate some guidance and advice.
Thanks!
Jim

Comment: Yup, I was right. It is a newbie question. The answer can be found here in great detail!
[http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products)